# Retrieving a field that does not belong to the model

Tags: c#, linq

Considere this piece of code in LINQ (please focus on var `list2`):

```
var list1 = .......  /* This linq doesnt matter. Just for clarify that it is used in the below linq */

var list2 = dba.OrderForm
    .Where(q => q.OrderPriority.OrderPriorityID == orderpriorityID
        && q.StockClass.StockClassID == stockclassID
        && dba.AuditTrailLog.Where(log => q.OrderID == log.ObjectID)
        .Any(log => log.ColumnInfoID == 486
            && log.OldValue == "2"
            && log.NewValue == "3")
            && dba.AuditTrailLog.Where(log2 => q.OrderID == log2.ObjectID)
            .Any(log2 => log2.ColumnInfoID == 487
                && log2.OldValue == "1"
                && log2.NewValue == "2")
                && lista.Contains(q.OrderID));
```

This way I have in list2 a list of records that belongs to `OrderForm` model. I need to pass it to another model called `ViewResult`:

What I need is to get the variable `log2.ModificationDate` that belongs to `AuditTrailLog` table but it is not included on `OrderForm` Model

```
List<ViewResult> vr = new List<ViewResult>();

foreach (OrderForm o in list2)
{
    ViewResult r = new ViewResult();
    r.NumOrden = o.FormNo;
    r.Title = o.Title;
    r.Com = o.OrderPriority.Descr;
    r.OClass = o.StockClass.Descr;
    r.RodT =   /*  <<------ Here is where I need to assign log2.ModificationDate

    vr.Add(r);              
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What I understand is `AuditTrailLog` relation is null while you are getting data. And you want to fill it with related data.

You must `Include` this table like:

(That means you are doing `join` on sql)

```
var list2 = dba.OrderForm.Include("AuditTrailLog")...
```

It is important the relation between them. "One to many" or "many to one". Use `AuditTrailLog` or `AuditTrailLogs` according to your relation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JustWork. Sorry if i didn't explain it correctly. The relation between `OrderForm-AuditTrailLog` is not null. What i need is retrieve in `r.RodT` de date when a every record of `OrderForm` table was modified (`log2.ModificationDate` in the LINQ) which is recorded in `AuditTraiLog` table.

Comment: The relation between `OrderForm/AuditTrailLog` tables is 1:N. I used `var list2 = dba.OrderForm.Include("AuditTrailLog")` as you suggested but I cannot perform `r.RodT = o.AuditTrailLog.ModificationDate` neither `r.RodT = log2.ModificationDate`

Comment: If there is ModificationDate value on AuditTrailLog table and you don't get it null while getting data, there is no way to you to cannot perform ModificationDate. You have something wrong. Or I understand you completely wrong. Did you debug it? Are you sure that AuditTrailLog is not null?

Comment: Yes I'm very sure. The LINQ is checking fine the ModificationDate that comply the conditions (1. `Exists a record with ColumnInfoID == 487' and OldValue == 2 and NewValue == 3`  &&  2.`Exists a record with ColumnInfoID == 486 and OldValue == 1 and NewValue == 2`).  what I need is to reference (for retrieving) the `ModificationDate` field of these records.